# What is the expected distortion of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, random-variables

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. I am interested in the "average distortion" caused by the action of $A$ on vectors. (i.e stretching or contraction of the norm).

Consider for instance the uniform distribution on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and the random variable $X:\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $X(x)=(\|A(x)\|_2)^2$.

**What is the expectation of $X$?**

Using SVD, it is easy to check that the problem reduces to $A$ being a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries. So, the question amounts to calculating $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma_ix_i)^2 $$ (and dividing by the volume of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$).

---

**Is there a closed formula for this integral?**

Also, one could take the expected value of the norm, and not its square (I thought this should be easier if there are no sqaure roots involved...)

Comment: You can swap $\int$ and $\sum$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the comment given by Hagen von Eitzen, we get:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma_ix_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} (\sigma_ix_i)^2= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} x_i^2$$

By symmetry, we see that $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} x_i^2$ is independent of the index $i$, hence:

$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} x_i^2=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} x_j^2 = \frac{1}{n} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2=\frac{1}{n} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} 1=\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$$

Hence the average distortion is:

$$E(X)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 $$